# Windows Phone Show Progress Indicator Each Link Click in Webbrowser Component

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I'm on small Windows phone project.

In this project, I use a WebBrowser component (like WebView in Android) to show the mobile website of my company as an application.

I need to show a progress bar/dialog/indicator whatever you say, after every link click.

How can I handle that? For example, I will click the news link and something will be shown to the user like loading etc.

**UPDATE :**

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Browser.Navigated += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs>(Browser_Navigated);
            Browser.Navigating += new EventHandler<NavigatingEventArgs>(Browser_Navigating);
            Browser.ScriptNotify += new EventHandler<NotifyEventArgs>(Browser_ScriptNotify);
        }

        void Browser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
        {
            Browser.Navigate(new Uri(e.Value, UriKind.Absolute));
        }

        void Browser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            ProgBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        void Browser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            ProgBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

i wrote this code but it doesnt show anything about progress.

Comment: OKAY ! My last update code worked.

Comment: Well done for wiring this all up. You probably want to show the overlay until `LoadComplete` is fired, I've seen that this can take 10s after `Navigated` in some cases. Also don't forget to wire up `NavigationFailed` :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use intercept the `Navigating` event of the `WebBrowser` control to start your progress bar.

You can just change the `Visibility` property of a loading overlay, say consisting of a semi-transparent `Rectangle` and a `ProgressBar`.

Then you should intercept the `LoadComplete` or `NavigationFailed` events and use these to remove your overlay.

Beware that some URLs (such as `tel:` links) don't fire the `Navigated` event, so you may need special handling for these.